# Android: application has stopped unexpectedly please try again Why?

Tags: android, android-layout, layoutparams

I want draw screen programmatically and not through layout-file. I write:

```
// create LayoutParams  
LayoutParams linLayoutParam = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 

// install linLayout  
setContentView(linLayout, linLayoutParam);
```

But my program do not start - I have message "application has stopped unexpectedly please try again", but my code is right (working). I think I have a problem with Android Virtual Device Manager, Maybe I must try running Fix Permissions in ROM Manager?, Else is it true - so How do it?

Android scolds line: `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;` - Why? Android wants to remove the line line: `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;` - Why? Maybe I have problem with Android Virtual Device Manager?, but How do running Fix Permissions in ROM Manager?

Comment: I don't understand.  `import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;`.  This is a compile time error correct?  But then you say your app crashes.  How can it crash, if you cannot compile it?

Comment: If your code was "working" you wouldn't have a crash. You have a crash, so your code is not working, and most likely isn't "right." First, resolve any compile-time problems, and then post your full code and your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All work! ))
I must use Android Virtual Device Manager 2.3.3, instead 4.0.

But maybe you write me links, that help me get outside of Android.